# How to extract the variables out from "add_shortcode" function in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, variables, shortcode

In Wordpress (now in Template Fiile), lets say i have a custom Shortcode function, like:

In the PAGE:

```
[myshortcode id='1234']
```

Then, in the Template File:

```
function parseUserID_func( $atts ){
    //parse the $atts here...
    $userID = 1234; //now i get the userID is, 1234
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'parseUserID_func' );
//now .. echo the value of $userID here? <----------
printout_UserDetails( $userID );
```

As you can see, how can i get the processed value of `$userID` variable out from the shortcode function please? (as in the last line)

---

**The `$userID` is not touchable from the outside.**

---

Actually what i'm trying to do is something like:

1. Pass an `ID` from the Page, using `[myshortcode id="1234"]`
2. Parse out the `id` from the shortcode's function. (`parseUserID_func` above)
3. When i get the `id`, i need to pass it to another custom `function printout_UserDetails($id){}` function (written in the Template File) .. to continue another processing works.
4. (Something like) then i will print out the `USER DETAILS` on the Page, from the `printout_UserDetails()` function.

This is why i need to pass a value from `Shortcode`, then parse it, then pass the `id` to my another custom function.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm understanding you're not trying to generate output with the shortcode, but to save data instead. I would try using custom fields to handle this.

If you need to output the "USER DETAILS" block within the post content (right where the shortcode is written), you should just merge the `printout_userDetials` logic into the actual shortcode handler function itself (in this case `parseUserID_func`).

Comment: I just need a way to GET a input/value passed from the page ---> to the Template File. (Then a function inside Template File will be able to use it.) You think the Custom Field would be better?

Comment: For that purpose yes. Custom fields are saved as separate values in the `wp_postmeta` database table, and you'll be able to use WordPress' `get_post_meta` function in your template file to fetch individual values (the inserted user ID value in your case) from there.

If you wish to create a more user-friendly interface for inserting the custom field value in the post edit form, check out some tutorials on how to create custom metaboxes in wp-admin (or alternatively use a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields to do the heavy lifting for you).

Comment: Yaa i can say using Custom Fields, is the acceptable solution. But anyway, for the knowledge, isn't there any way to grab/take out a variable returned from the Shortcode Function, please?

Comment: You can extract the shortcode parameters and use them inside the shortcode parser function itself. Perhaps by adding a custom hook (with `do_action` or `apply_filters`) inside the template (which is executed after your shortcode) you could try using the shortcode parameters via an `add_action`/`add_filter` call.